# Source code for Python's modules

Tags: python

Is it possible to view the source code of Python's functions like `sum`, `zip` and the like? I just want to know about the implementation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can download it here:

http://www.python.org/getit/source/

Comment: The source of the modules is (fairly obviously) in the Modules directory.

Comment: sum and zip aren't modules though. He's asking about the backend C code.

Answer (score 6):

Source for builtins functions (like `sum`, `zip`, etc) are in http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/57c157be847f/Python/bltinmodule.c.

Answer (score 2):

You cant see the code for the sum and zip because those are wrapper of c functions. But other module you can check on http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the location of the Python source code files on disk:

```
import sys
print(["%s %s" % (k,v) for k,v in sys,modules.items()] if k == "re")
```

On Windows, it is usually found on `C:\python33\lib\`. and on Linux it is `/usr/python2.7/lib/...`.

Once there, you can view the .py files as you wish.

Comment: I think OP is asking for the C source code of the internal funcions like sum, min, max, reduce and so on